# Jquery access table cell widths

Tags: jquery

I have a series of tables where each one's ID value ends with the same string, e.g.

```
<table id="ctl01_mytable" .../>
<table id="ctl02_mytable" .../>
<table id="ctl03_mytable" .../>
```

I am trying to achieve the following in JQuery to ensure that the width of the first column of each table is set to the same value (the widest width of all, so that the first column of each table has a matching width).

```
    function matchWidths() {
        var w = 0;
        // find widest cell
        $("table[id$='mytable'] tr td:first").each(function () {
            alert($(this).width()); // debug

            //if ($(this).width() > w) {
            //  w = $(this).width();
            //}

        });
        // set all cells to widest across child tables
        $("table[id$='gv_selfAllocSkills'] tr td:first").each(function () {
            //$(this).width(w);
        });
    }
```

When I run the above code, only the width of the first table, first cell is returned, then the loop exits.  Can anyone advise how to get JQuery to cycle through all the first table cells of each matching table?

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle showing the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try `:first-child` instead of `:first`

```
var w = 0;        
$("table[id$='mytable'] tr td:first-child").each(function () {            
    if ($(this).width() > w) {
        w = $(this).width();
    }
});            
$("table[id$='mytable'] tr td:first-child").each(function () {
    $(this).css('width', w);
});
```

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6gjDx/)**

Answer (score 1):

Basically `:first` will return the first element from the element collection, So the way you are following to select the first `td` of all `tr` is wrong.

You can change your code like this to achieve your need,

```
$("table[id$='mytable'] tr").each(function () {   
alert($(this).children('td').filter(':first').width());
//and your code goes here
});
```

As an alternate you could also use `nth-child` selector like this,

```
$(window).on('load', matchWidths);

function matchWidths() {
    var w = 0;

    $("table[id$='mytable'] tr td:nth-child(1)").each(function () {
        if ($(this).width() > w) {
            w = $(this).width();
        }
    });

    $("table[id$='gv_selfAllocSkills'] tr td:nth-child(1)").width(w);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`tr td:first` returns one single element, the first in the collection, you're probably looking for

```
tr td:first-child
```

so something like this :

```
$(window).on('load', matchWidths);

function matchWidths() {
    var w = 0;

    $("table[id$='mytable'] tr td:first-child").each(function () {
        if ($(this).width() > w) {
            w = $(this).width();
        }
    });

    $("table[id$='gv_selfAllocSkills'] tr td:first-child").width(w);
}
```